# how the difference between libevent version 1.4 and 2.0 influence libpcap events?

Tags: network-programming, libpcap, libevent

I'm using libpcap and libevent in a program.

the related source codes are:

```
const u_int16_t RELAY_PORT = 8000;

pcap_t *create_pcap(const void *dev, pcap_style_t style)
{
    pcap_t *handle;                 /* Session handle */
    struct bpf_program fp;          /* The compiled filter */
    bpf_u_int32 mask;               /* The netmask */
    bpf_u_int32 net;                /* The IP subnet*/
    const struct pcap_pkthdr* pcap_header;   /* A pointer to pcap_pkthdr structure */
    const u_char *pcap_packet;           /* The captured packet */ 

    char interface[20];
    strcpy(interface, dev);

    /* Find the properties for the network interface */
    if (pcap_lookupnet(interface, &net, &mask, errbuf) == -1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Pcap counldn't get netmask for device %s: %s\n", interface, errbuf);
      net = 0;
      mask = 0;
    }


    handle = pcap_open_live(interface, BUFSIZ, 0, 0, errbuf);
    if (handle == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Pcap open live capture failure: %s\n", errbuf);
            exit(1); 
    }

    sprintf(filter_exp, "tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn|tcp-ack) == (tcp-syn|tcp-ack) && src port %d || dst port %d", RELAY_PORT, RELAY_PORT);

    /* Compile and apply the filter */
    if (pcap_compile(handle, &fp, filter_exp, 0, mask) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Pcap parse filter failure: %s\n", pcap_geterr(handle));
        exit(1);
    }

    if (pcap_setfilter(handle, &fp) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Pcap couldn't install filter: %s\n", pcap_geterr(handle));
        exit(1);
    }

    if(style == NONBLOCKING){
       if(pcap_setnonblock(handle, 1, errbuf) == -1){
            fprintf(stderr, "Pcap set non-blocking fails: %s\n", errbuf);
                exit(1);
      }
    }

   return handle;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

void on_capture(int pcapfd, short op, void *arg)
{
   int res;
   printf("on capture \n");
   pcap_t *handle;
   handle = (pcap_t *)arg;
   fqueue_t* pkt_queue;

   /* put all packets in the buffer into the packet FIFO queue
   * and then process these packets 
   * */
    pkt_queue = init_fqueue();
    res = pcap_dispatch(handle, -1, collect_pkt, (u_char *)pkt_queue);
    printf("pcap_dispatch() returns %d\n", res);
    if(!res) return;
    process_packet(pkt_queue);
}

//////////////////

 int pcapfd;
 pcap_t *pcap_handle;
 struct event  pcap_ev;

 pcap_handle = create_pcap("eth0", NONBLOCKING);  
 pcapfd = pcap_get_selectable_fd(pcap_handle);
 if(pcapfd<0){
    perror("pcap_get_selectable_fd() failed!\n");
    exit(1);
 }

 if (setnonblock(pcapfd) == -1) return -1;

 base = event_init();

 event_set(&pcap_ev, pcapfd, EV_READ|EV_PERSIST, on_capture,  pcap_handle);
 event_base_set(base, &pcap_ev);
 if(event_add(&pcap_ev, NULL) == -1){
    perror("event_add() failed for pcap_ev!\n");
    exit(-1);
 }

  event_base_dispatch(base);
---------------------------------------------
```

I also register two TCP events on event_base( on_accept and on_recv.)

then I run the program on host A and host B send packets to A, meanwhile I use a tcpdump to capture packets on A  (tcpdump -i eth0  port 8000 )

For comparison, I have two laptops which acts as A, I tried the program (compile and then run) on these two laptops, one with Fedora (fedora release 18) and one with Ubuntu (Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS)

```
ubuntu: Linux 3.13.0-61-generic
fedora: Linux 3.11.10-100-fc18.x86_64
```

on ubuntu events are invoked in the following order

```
on capture 
pcap_dispatch() returns 0
on capture 
pcap_dispatch() returns 0
on accept 
on recv
```

it is strange that the pcap_dispatch returns 0 twice. My expectation is that the when on_capture event is triggered, pcap_dispatch will catch TCP SYN packets before on_accept event is triggered (TCP packets are captured on NIC before handed over to TCP stack). But I don't know why the on_capture events are invoked twice and pcap_dispatch()  returns 0.

on Fedora, the program works as expected, the pcap_dispatch() can capture packets the first time it is invoked before on_accept event.

I use `ldd` to check the libraries of this program on each laptop.

Fedora:

```
 $ldd relay 
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff1d1ad000)
libevent-1.4.so.2 => /lib/libevent-1.4.so.2 (0x00007faca467d000)
libpcap.so.1 => /lib64/libpcap.so.1 (0x00000035b4a00000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00000035b0a00000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00000035cea00000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00000035b1a00000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00000035b2e00000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000035b0200000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00000035b1600000)
```

ubuntu:

```
  $ ldd relay 
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd08bc5000)
libevent-2.0.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent-2.0.so.5 (0x00007eff35f81000)
libpcap.so.0.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.so.0.8 (0x00007eff35d43000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007eff3597e000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007eff35760000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007eff361c5000)
```

indeed, both libpcap and libevent versions are different.
what are potential problems for my program when it runs on ubuntu? how can fix the unexpected problems on ubuntu?
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how the difference between libevent version 1.4 and 2.0 influence libpcap events?

It doesn't.

> indeed, both libpcap and libevent versions are different

Yes; as you indicated in your email to me, the libpcap on Fedora is libpcap 1.3.0 and the libpcap on Ubuntu is libpcap 1.5.3.

Libpcap 1.3.0 doesn't support TPACKET_V3, and libpcap 1.5.3 does.  The kernel on both your Fedora machine (3.11.10-100-fc18.x86_64, according to your email) and your Ubuntu machine (3.13.0-61-generic, according to your email) both support TPACKET_V3.

> how can fix the unexpected problems on ubuntu?

Don't use a timeout of 0 in the `pcap_open_live()` call.  Due to the way TPACKET_V3 works, some bugs in how it works in older kernels (both of your kernels are "older" in that sense), and the way libpcap attempts to make non-blocking mode work, make a timeout of 0 work, and work around those bugs, a timeout of 0 may not work well.  Try a timeout of, for example, 100 (for 1/10 of a second) or 10 (for 1/100 of a second).

Note that if a timeout of 0 works the way it's intended, it could be that an event for libpcap might not be delivered for an arbitrarily-long period of time, with the time period being longer the less traffic is captured, so it's rarely, if ever, a good idea to use a timeout of 0.

Comment: I don't get it. If I set timeout to be 1/10 second(or 1/100, whatever), it means if there are no packets arriving, the pcap event will still be frequently triggered, which is not desirable, isn't it? besides, what does timeout=-1 mean?

Comment: I read your answer and this post https://github.com/jvinet/knock/issues/5. So basically there are two reasons why timeout=0 should not be used: 1) it may increase the burden on CPU 2) "enough packets to arrive" can mean "enough packets to fill up a buffer" on Linux, which requires a long time. But it seems to me 1) and 2) conflicts with each other. Isn't it? are there any other reasons that timeout=0 should not be used?

Comment: "the pcap event will still be frequently triggered, which is not desirable, isn't it?"  Given the kernel bugs I mentioned, yes, it *is* desirable; see https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/issues/335#issuecomment-30280794 (and trust me on this one - that's really what happens, as I discovered when fixing that bug; if you don't think that explanation makes sense, you're missing something).

Comment: "besides, what does timeout=-1 mean?"  If by "timeout = -1" you mean "you specified -1 as a timeout to `pcap_open_live()` or `pcap_set_timeout()`, then what it means is "your code is buggy and doing something that will result in unpredictable and platform-dependent behavior".

Comment: "So basically there are two reasons why timeout=0 should not be used: 1) it may increase the burden on CPU"  If you're referring to the short timeout causing lots of wakeups, that's a problem specific to Linux kernels with a buggy version of TPACKET_V3.  "2) "enough packets to arrive" can mean "enough packets to fill up a buffer" on Linux, which requires a long time"  It can mean "enough packets to fill up a buffer" on \*BSD, OS X, and Solaris 11. On Linux with TPACKET_V3, the *kernel* doesn't support an infinite timeout - 0 means "calculate what you think is an appropriate timeout".

Comment: (continued) libpcap, on Linux with TPACKET_V3, implements the "infinite timeout" itself, which means that you get wakeups that don't deliver any packets (which consumes CPU, but it has to be done in order to remove the empty buffers that the kernel delivers, otherwise the entire buffer ring is filled and incoming packets are dropped rather than being delivered to the sniffing application), *but*, as the application specified a timeout of 0, when that happens `pcap_dispatch()` doesn't return 0, it just keeps looping waiting for packets.